# Regex Capturing Groups in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, regex

I know this is a extremely simple question but Regex confuses me to no end.

I have created this Regex:

```
DataAt\((.)\)
```

to capture

```
DataAt(5)
```

and replace it with

```
DataAt(5).get()
```

I have tried this in the `Find and Replace` box for a capturing group:

```
DataAt($1).get()
```

But it just changes it to

```
DataAt($1).get()
```

How can I get the desired results? Thanks and sorry for the easy question.

Comment: What regex library are you using and how are you using it?

Comment: Im using search and replace in Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to reproduce the `DataAt` portion you should capture it to a group also:

```
(DataAt)\((.)\)
```

Then use something such as this to replace:

```
$1($2).get()
```

To result in:

```
DataAt(5).get()
```

Otherwise your only capture group is what is inside `( )`.

EDIT: It was determined that the regex replacement is within Visual Studio. With older versions defining a capture group requires the use of curly braces `{ }` and backreferences using `\1`, `\2`, etc. . So in this instance it would be used like:

```
\DataAt\({.}\)
```

Replace with:

```
DataAt(\1).get()
```

Comment: @marsh, I'm not sure which `replace box` you are referring to, although using `$1` or `\1`, etc. would normally be the standard regex replace variables.

Comment: I do not need to capture DataAt as well just what is inside the brackets. I am not sure why it is not working with my example you seem to be saying it should have worked.

Comment: Yes it should have worked. But where are you using this replace pattern? You mentioned `replace box`? I have no idea which replace box you are referring to, there could be a million possibilities.

Comment: Yea sorry I worded that badly. I am doing this in Visual Studio search and replace window. So what I put into the replace section was DataAt($1).get()

Comment: Ah ok, in VS it's slightly different. They use curly brackets to define capturing groups instead of parentheses (at least was the case for older versions). For Visual Studio 2010 it would be: `\DataAt\({.}\)`, then replace with `DataAt(\1).get()`. For later versions of Visual Studio you should be able to use `()` for capturing groups and `$1` instead of `\1`. Also in `Find and Replace` make sure you have `Use > Regular Expressions` checked on.